# Why is my C# Socket server not allowing multiple instances of the client to connect, only from the local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have previously had this code working, and am unsure of the cause of the issue i am currently having. I am writing a simple client/server application for encrypted chat. The server allows for multiple simultaneous clients. When i bind the server to the local IP Address i can connect with multiple local clients simultaneously, but when I bind it to the external IP address, only the first instance on the local machine will connect, but other devices may connect with multiple instances simultaneously. In this case even closing the first instance will not allow another to connect, and the AcceptCallBack is never called. I have been unable to find any other reports of this issue. Reasons that come to mind include that I made some sort of mistake in the code, or I need to separately listen for local connections and remote connections, or that it is a router/firewall issue.

For my server i have:

```
public partial class frmServer : Form
{   

    Thread listenThread;
    private static bool listening = false;
    private static List<StateObject> Users = new List<StateObject>();

    public frmServer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void frmServer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListening));
                listenThread.Start();
            }
            public static void StartListening()
            {
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 19541);

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
                Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
                try
                {

                    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);               
                    listener.Listen(100);
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                           new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                           listener);
                    listening = true;
                    while (true)
                    {                           
                        //check if there are new connections
                        if (!listening)
                        {
                            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                            listening = true;
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
             public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);            
            listening = false;
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            Users.Add(state);            
        }
}
 public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //user info
}
```

And For the client i have

```
public partial class frmClient : Form
{        

    public frmClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }  

    private void frmClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartClient();            
    }

    private void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.   
             IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("Remote Host Address");                
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP V4 socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);    

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            // Signal that the connection has been made. 
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());                 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you start your server as admin? Also your port needs to be enabled in your Windows and routers firewalls to accept external connections. I know that at least for HTTP/WebAPI servers you need proper privileges in order to be able to listen on external addresses or by granting a non-admin user the privileges via [netsh add urlacl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl), but I don’t know how it’s with socket connections.

Comment: You may wish to `lock` on `Users` before `Add`ing to it.

Comment: @ckuri hmm.. Starting it as administrator changed nothing, and the connections are functioning flawlessly when they originate from an external source, even 10 simultaneous connections. And they function the first time i connect locally. Just not from multiple local clients at once or even from a second local client after the first is closed.

Comment: Okay :), yeah i just added the users list and that is when i noticed the issue. I just fixated on the problem and didn't really flesh out the code any more after that